# external configuration on classpath per application in jboss

Tags: java, configuration, jboss, classpath

i'm completely noob with jboss administration. i want to have a few applications (wars) on jboss. each of them should have external configuration - file or better directory, available on classpath. and of course one application must not see configuration of other application. they must have completely different classpath. is it possible to do that? how?

Comment: actually i don't have any specific version. i'm asking for a general solution. but if there is none then i'm especially interested in JBoss [EAP] 5.1.1  and JBoss [EAP] 4.3.0.GA_CP06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your server profile to pick up applications from several external folders( https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToDeployMyApplicationInAnExternalDirectoryInJBoss-5?_sscc=t ) and then just set permission for each of that folder

Comment: deploying application is not a problem. but let's say i have 2 different apps with external configuration file (outside war, let's say log4j.xml). and each of those application expects file with the same name to be on the classpath. so how can i provide two different files with the same name so each of the applications can see *only* its own file?

Comment: currently it is impossible, when server starts up it uses only one server profile configs, and classpath can't have two same resources. The only solution is to start two jboss instances on machine.